# Jenkins parameters default to env variable?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, jenkins2

I am trying to crate parameters field which is default to current build no.

```
parameters {
    string(
        name: 'DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER',
        defaultValue: '${BUILD_NUMBER}',
        description: 'Fresh Build and Deploy OR Deploy Previous Build Number'
    )
}
```

But it looks like the assignment of `BUILD_NUMBER` env var to parameter `DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER` is not happening.

even following one didn't help

```
steps {
        script {
            if (params.DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER == null){
                DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER = env.BUILD_NUMBER
            }
        }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: I can only guess that the BUILD_NUMBER env var is not yet populated in the stage of reading the build parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.  Single-quoted strings don't perform string interpolation.

For instance:

```
parameters {
    string(
        name: 'DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER',
        defaultValue: "${BUILD_NUMBER}",
        description: 'Fresh Build and Deploy OR Deploy Previous Build Number'
    )
}
```

Comment: after this change, `echo "${DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER}"` prints `env.BUILD_NUMBER`. How can I get actual value of `env.BUILD_NUMBER`, when I refer to `${DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER}`